# С#: сравнение файла на веб-ресурсе и локальный файл

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, файлы, сравнение

Есть веб-сайт, на нем ссылка для скачивая файла "А". Есть локальная версия файла А. Как можно их сравнить, чтобы не скачивать файл с интернета?

Есть идея  сравнивать контрольные суммы, но для этого файл с инета придется скачать.

Как-то это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это поможет? Сравнивать даты.
Наткнулся на просторах Интернета.
http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread1346241.html

Answer (score 2):

Только через Head запрос, сервер выдаст информацию о файле в виде заголовка, ну и остальное от сервера зависит, и нужно по ответ Athari проверить заголовки

Answer (score 1):

Есть элегантное решение с помощью bash однострочника

```
diff myFile <(ssh myHost 'cat myFile')
```

И да можно сравнить два файла которые вообще на разных хостах с помощью третьего хоста.

```
diff <(ssh myHost1 'cat myFile') <(ssh myHost2 'cat myFile')
```

Правда это конечно создаст SSH траффик примерно равный размеру файла, но фактически файл скорее всего не будет скачан на жесткий диск.

P.S. Вместо cat можно написать md5sum, а diff заменить на if , чтобы сравнить хэши, совсем избавившись от траффика. Правда в таком случае будет непонятно чем конкретно файлы отличаются.

Comment: С таким же успехом можно скачать файл в память, никто не заставляет сохранять данные на диск. Ну и с кросс-платформенностью у вас не очень. Так как вопрос по C#, то поддержку винды я бы подразумевал по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, поддерживает ли веб-сервер кэширование для файлов. Для этого используются заголовки типа "ETag", "Cache-Control" и другие. Например, если сервер при скачивании файла указывает "ETag", то вы можете запомнить эту строчку и при повторном запросе указать её в заголовке "If-None-Match". Если файл на сервере не изменился, то сервер вернёт вам соответствующий HTTP код (304 Not Modified) с пустым телом ответа, то есть будут скачаны только HTTP заголовки, но не сам файл.

См. [HTTP ETag](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).